# How to disable the download of the auto-reconfiguration-1.10.0 RELEASE.jar when the CF app is starting

Tags: cloud-foundry

When we start the Cloud Foundry application it downloads the auto-reconfiguration.jar from the java-buildpack.cloudfoundry.org.

"Downloading Auto Reconfiguration 1.10.0_RELEASE from https://java-buildpack.cloudfoundry.org/auto-reconfiguration/auto-reconfiguration-1.10.0_RELEASE.jar"

1. How to disable the download of the auto-reconfiguration jar file?
2. What changes to make in the CF App to use the bundled auto-reconfiguration jar file ?

Answer (score 0):

> 1. How to disable the download of the auto-reconfiguration jar file?

To disable the Java Buildpack auto-reconfiguration feature, set an environment variable on the deployed app like this:

`cf set-env my-app JBP_CONFIG_SPRING_AUTO_RECONFIGURATION: '{enabled: false}'`

> 2. What changes to make in the CF App to use the bundled auto-reconfiguration jar file?

You don't make any changes you your app to use auto-reconfiguration. When the jar file is present on the classpath, it automatically re-configures certain types of Spring beans it finds in the application context. See [the docs](https://github.com/cloudfoundry/java-buildpack-auto-reconfiguration#what-is-auto-reconfiguration) for more details.